# What do "snapper mount" and "snapper umount" do?

Tags: btrfs

I'm using snapper with BTRFS under Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm confused about the "mount" and "umount" parameters. They are documented like this in the man page:

```
   mount number
       Mount a snapshot. Not required for all filesystem types.

   umount number
       Unmount a snapshot. Not required for all filesystem types.
```

But where are the snapshots mounted? Does snapper read my mind to know, or just makes an educated guess?

I know how to mount the snapshots using "mount" and the subvol ID, but I would like to know if these "mount" and "umount" options are just a joke  or something you can actually use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oddly enough these are in `snapper --help` but not in `man snapper`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`snapper mount` and `snapper umount` are really only useful when snapper is used with thin-provisioned LVM snapshots. Theese commands will mount and unmount LVM snapshots in the `.snapshots/$number/snapshot` directory.

Since btrfs subvolumes are always accessible form the `.snapshots` directory without having to be mounted, `snapper mount` and `snapper umount` don't do anything with btrfs.

Comment: I hadn't seen your reply until now, sorry. I'm marking it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The snapshots are located in a directory called .snapshots in the subvolume.  There is a directory corresponding to each snapshot number.  I personally can't figure out what mount and umount do.  I was unable to find any more information on it than you did.